# Python: Efficient way of sorting dictionary that has n dictionaries within it

Tags: python, data-structures

I'll just go straight to example:

Here we have a dictionary with a test name, and another dict which contains the level categorization.

**EDIT**

```
       Input: 

      test_values={  
   {  
      "name":"test1",
      "level_map":{  
         "system":1,
         "system_apps":2,
         "app_test":3
      }
   },
   {  
      "name":"test2",
      "level_map":{  
         "system":1,
         "system_apps":2,
         "app_test":3
      }
   },
   {  
      "name":"test3",
      "level_map":{  
         "system":1,
         "memory":2,
         "memory_test":3
      }
   }
}


Output:

What I want is this:

dict_obj:

{  
   "system":{  
      "system_apps":{  
         "app_test":{  
            test1 object,
            test2 object
         },
         "memory":{  
            "memory_test":{  
               test3 object
            }
         }
      }
   }
```

I just can't wrap my head around the logic and I'm struggling to even come up with an approach. If someone could guide me, that would be great.

Comment: Sorry about that. Edited my post.

Comment: Yes it is a list of dicts. I was going to loop through each item of the input, construct the output object and append the item as the value. However, I'm totally lost and been thinking about this for hours with no progress.

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh Thanks for helping but jferard answered it perfectly. My attempt was pretty much exactly the same as his solution, however, I was missing the idea of sorting the levels first to create a list, and then using them to build a tree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start with level_map. You can sort keys on values to get the ordered levels:

```
>>> level_map = { "system": 1, "system_apps": 2, "app_test": 3}
>>> L = sorted(level_map.keys(), key=lambda k: level_map[k])
>>> L
['system', 'system_apps', 'app_test']
```

Use these elements to build a *tree*:

```
>>> root = {}
>>> temp = root
>>> for k in L[:-1]:
...     temp = temp.setdefault(k, {}) # create new inner dict if necessary
...
>>> temp.setdefault(L[-1], []).append("test") # and add a name
>>> root
{'system': {'system_apps': {'app_test': ['test']}}}
```

I split the list before the last element, because the last element will be associated to a list, not a dict (leaves of the tree are lists in your example).

Now, the it's easy to repeat this with the list of dicts:

```
ds = [{ "name": "test1",
      "level_map": { "system": 1, "system_apps": 2, "app_test": 3}
    }, { "name": "test2",
     "level_map": { "system": 1, "system_apps": 2, "app_test": 3}
    }, { "name": "test3",
     "level_map": { "system": 1, "memory": 2, "memory_test": 3}
    }]


root = {}
for d in ds:
    name = d["name"]
    level_map = d["level_map"]
    L = sorted(level_map.keys(), key=lambda k: level_map[k])
    temp = root
    for k in L[:-1]:
        temp = temp.setdefault(k, {})
    temp.setdefault(L[-1], []).append(name)

# root is: {'system': {'system_apps': {'app_test': ['test1', 'test2']}, 'memory': {'memory_test': ['test3']}}}
```

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you so much.